# Screen brightness not working Acer Swift AMD Ryzen5 (elementaryos)

Tags: ubuntu

Complete n00b at linux. (and to be honest most things command line) trying desperately to figure out why I cannot change the displays backlight brightness. When I adjust it via the keyboard shortcuts the brigtness bar reacts but the actual display brightness does not.

I have tried adjusting it in settings and power settings. I have duckduckgo'ed my a** off and found all kinda suggestions, and all to no avail. I ran `lshw -c video` and confirmed that the driver looks like an AMD driver. so That doesn't seem to be it.

Anyone willing to help a fellow nerd trying to escape the watchful eye of microsoft? :)

model number is : SF314-42-R7RK

```
*-display UNCLAIMED
description: VGA compatible controller
product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
version: c3
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c01fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:c0600000-c067ffff
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the model of your Acer? Thus will make it much simpler to offer a specific solution 

Comment: Cannot update my question since I was dumb enough to make it as a guest. but the model number is : SF314-42-R7RK